# How do you know if a nucleophile is strong enough to to break a bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

For instance, iodine can displace bromine in $\ce{CH3Br}$ Is this due to iodine being lower in the periodic table, thus having more electrons in the outer shell and being a stronger nucleophile?

Comment: It doesn’t have more electrons on outer shell...

Comment: In a simplistic way you can say that, due to the less effective charge of iodine outer electrons respect to bromine, it will be more likely to react, and will replace bromine. But to say it exactly you need Gibbs free energy, if reaction occurs and constant T and P...